# Understanding Intnx statement in SAS

Tags: sas

It's been a while since I have done anything in SAS, I'm going through some legacy code where I found the following statement in `data` step:

```
variable_month = Intnx("Month",some_date,0,"B");
```

According to the documentation [`Intnx`](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en):

> Increments a date, time, or datetime value by a given time interval, and returns a date, time, or datetime value.

However, when I try to run the following code:

```
data _null_;
    *Mirror SAS code statement;
    date1=Intnx('Month', '01aug11:00:10:48'dt, 0, "B");
    put 'Results   ' date1= datetime19. ;
run;
```

I'm getting error message:

> NOTE: Invalid argument to function INTNX('Month',1627776648,0,'B') at
>   line 30 column 8.

## Question

What was the aim behind the original `Intnx` statement? To get the month from date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up datetimes and dates.

The original code would have aligned a date to the beginning of the `month`. 
You used an interval of month but provided a datetime value not a date value. To use this correctly you would need to use `dtMonth` as your interval to get the same behaviour. It would align the date to the beginning of the period specified.

```
date1=Intnx('dtMonth', '01aug11:00:10:48'dt, 0, "B");
```